# CSS Basics: Setting a table font to Verdana 9

Tags: css

I'm trying to set the font in a table to Verdana 9 but seem to only be setting it to 10.5.  The format is intended to be posted into an Outlook signature.

My basic CSS for the page below is basic.  Have I set something up incorrectly?

```css
<style>
body {
 font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
} 
h1 {
 font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
 font-size: 24px;
 font-style: normal;
 font-variant: normal;
 font-weight: 500;
 line-height: 26.4px;
}
h3 {
 font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
 font-size: 14px;
 font-style: normal;
 font-variant: normal;
 font-weight: 500;
 line-height: 15.4px;
}
p {
 font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
 font-size: 14px;
 font-style: normal;
 font-variant: normal;
 font-weight: 400;
 line-height: 20px;
}
blockquote {
 font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
 font-size: 21px;
 font-style: normal;
 font-variant: normal;
 font-weight: 400;
 line-height: 30px;
}
pre {
 font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
 font-size: 13px;
 font-style: normal;
 font-variant: normal;
 font-weight: 400;
 line-height: 18.5714px;

table {
 font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
 font-size: 9px;
 font-style: normal;
 font-variant: normal;
 
</style>
```

Comment: instead of `table{}` use `td,th{}` in your css rules

Comment: Agreed Andrew, will be tidying this up closely.  Time was a constraint sadly.  Thanks for the good form suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

The last two blocks do not have a closing bracket:

```
pre {
    font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-style: normal;
    font-variant: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 18.5714px;
}
table {
    font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
    font-size: 9px;
    font-style: normal;
    font-variant: normal;
}
```

Comment: What a daft...dafty..,mistake.  let me amend.  Thank you muchly.  Will test.